# Simplify data packet assemble in C

Tags: c

Below code just for assemble data into network packet. but the code logic has many repeat parts to convert integer for byte array. what's the best method for such purpose to simplify below logic?

```
typedef struct _INFO {
    int pid;
    int score;
} INFO;

void send_packet(int connfd,INFO* info,int len) {
    int buflen = len*8 + 8;
    unsigned char* buf = (int*)malloc(buflen);
    int p = 0;
    buf[p++] = 0x55;
    buf[p++] = 0x55;
    buf[p++] = 0x55;
    buf[p++] = 0x55;

    buf[p++] = buflen & 0xFF;
    buf[p++] = (buflen >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buf[p++] = (buflen >> 16) & 0xFF;
    buf[p++] = (buflen >> 24) & 0xFF;
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        buf[p++] = info[i].pid & 0xFF;
        buf[p++] = (info[i].pid >> 8) & 0xFF;
        buf[p++] = (info[i].pid >> 16) & 0xFF;
        buf[p++] = (info[i].pid >> 24) & 0xFF;

        buf[p++] = info[i].score & 0xFF;
        buf[p++] = (info[i].score >> 8) & 0xFF;
        buf[p++] = (info[i].score >> 16) & 0xFF;
        buf[p++] = (info[i].score >> 24) & 0xFF;
    }
    write(connfd, buf, buflen);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: What is the potential range of `len`?

Comment: BTW, a leading `0x55555555` looks like it has some weakness for the `read()` side to synchronize with.  I look forward to seeing the read code.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, for synchronize purpose, any keyword can be used I guess. some hardware guy tell me use 0x55555555. what's your suggestion?

Comment: Ideally the start-of-frame bytes never/rarely occur in the payload and don't look like a start-of-frame shifted with the beginning/trailing byte.  Yet there is more than just good  start-of-frame selection such as [What type of framing to use in serial communication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17073302/2410359)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's the best method for such purpose to simplify below logic?

With a helper function as there is  repetitive code.

```
#include <stdint.h>

// Write 32-bit integer in little endian order to buf
unsigned char *u32tobuf(unsigned char *buf, uint32_t value) {
  buf[0] = value;
  buf[1] = value >> 8;
  buf[2] = value >> 16;
  buf[3] = value >> 24;
  return buf + 4;
}
```

I'd also 1) add some error checking, 2) drop the unneeded cast 3) prevent `int` overflow 4) use `const`.

```
// Return error status
int send_packet(int connfd, const INFO* info, int len) {
    uint32_t buflen = len*8lu + 8;
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(buflen);
    if (buf == NULL) {
      return 1; // or perhaps some enum
    }
    unsigned char* p = u32tobuf(buf, 0x55555555);
    p = u32tobuf(p, buflen);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
      p = u32tobuf(p, info[i].pid);
      p = u32tobuf(p, info[i].score);
    }
    ssize_t write_count = write(connfd, buf, buflen);
    free(buf);
    if (write_count != buflen) [
      return 1; // or perhaps some enum
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, the cast is means & 0xFF? I saw java use such cast always. for C, I am not sure if we need it.

Comment: @lucky1928 _Casting_ does has its place, yet it is often a sign of brittle learner's.code.  With converting a `void *` to/from some other `object *`, it is not needed in C.

Comment: Oh, the buf pointer has been moved to the end, so the write will be overflow. need to add a variable to remember the pointer header.

Comment: @lucky1928 Yes code was amended

Comment: could a union be used to simplify the u32tobuf function?

Comment: As the goal is to take a 32-bit of host endian into a serial buffer for transmission, I doubt a `union` will provide a performance increase nor simplification.

Answer (score 2):

A 0xFF character is all ones. So `AnyChar & 0xFF` will always return the same char. Also you can simplify the first 4 lines with `memset()`. You can also simplify a few of the lines with for loops:

```
#include <string.h>
void send_packet(int connfd,INFO* info,int len) {
    int buflen = len*8 + 8;
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(buflen);
    int p = 4;
    memset(buf, 0x55, 4);

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        buf[p++] = buflen >> i*8;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            buf[p++] = info[i].pid >> i*8;
            buf[p++] = info[i].score >> i*8;
        }
    }
    write(connfd, buf, buflen);
    free(buf);
}
```

Comment: memset is awesome!

Comment: @lucky1928 Indeed

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            buf[p++] = info[i].pid >> i*8;
            buf[p++] = info[i].score >> i*8;
        }` needs to be 2 loops.

Comment: The code contains way too many `for` loops that have exactly the same structure.